# Fast String within List Searching

Tags: python, string, performance, list

Using Python 3, I have a list containing over 100,000 strings (list1), each 300 characters long at most. I also have a list of over 9 million substrings (list2)--I want to count how many elements a substring in list2 appears in. For instance,

```
list1 = ['cat', 'caa', 'doa', 'oat']
list2 = ['at', 'ca', 'do']
```

I want the function to return (mapped to list2):

```
[2, 2, 1]
```

Normally, this is very simple and requires very little. However, due to the massive size of the lists, I have efficiency issues. I want to find the fastest way to return that counter list.

I've tried list comprehensions, generators, maps, loops of all kinds and I have yet to find an fast way to do this easy task. What is theoretically the fastest way to complete this objective, preferably taking `O(len(list2))` steps very quickly?

Answer (score 2):

set `M = len(list1)` and `N = len(list2)`

For each of the N entries in `list2` you're going to have to do M comparisons against the entries in `list1`. That's a worst case running time of `O(M x N)`. If you take it further, lets take each entry in `list2` to be of length 1 and each entry in `list1` to be of length 300, then you got a running time of `O(300M x N)`.

If performance is really an issue, try dynamic programming. Here is a start:

1) sort `list2` in ascending order of length like so:

```
['scorch', 'scorching', 'dump', 'dumpster', 'dumpsters']
```

2) sort them into sublists such that each preceeding entry is a subset of the proceeding entry like so:

```
[['scorch', 'scorching'] , ['dump', 'dumpster', 'dumpsters']]
```

3) Now if you compare against `list1` and `'scorch'` is not in there, then you don't have to search for `'scorching'` either. Likewise if `'dump'` is not in there, neither is `'dumpster'` or `'dumpsters'`

note the worst case run time is still the same

Comment: That's a good idea, but each substring in list2 is in at least one element of list1.

Comment: This will require a great deal of overhead, but you could try indexing both `list1` and `list2` based on the characters they have, so if an entry of `list1` is `'abcd'` you wouldn't check the `list2` entry `'efg'`, only the `list2` entries which fall under the path/branch of `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` or `'d'`

Comment: The same amount of steps would be taken though, right? Right now, for each substring in list2 I count by `sum(1 for string in list1 if substring in string)`. Wouldn't the process of checking for characters not included take the same amount of time as the if/in statement?

Comment: @user1104160 I could be mistaken, but I don't think you can get around the worst case scenario of `O(300MxN)`. If this is something that gets called quite often, I recommend taking the time to index, in a massive tree/array, based on length and/or letters

Comment: Shoot. I was hoping that there would be some magic built-in function related to "count" that I could call that would be much faster than what I am doing now. The processes is done once, but it would take a very, very long time to run and it needs to done for like 10 different sets.

Comment: Hold on, I am trying to create a small example for you...man what a lousy way to spend one's Friday

Comment: @user1104160 Wow, what exactly are you doing? I am trying to create 9 million randomly generated strings and it has taken over 5 minutes now

Comment: Genomics. 9 million is on the small side.

Comment: Oddly enough getting the 9 million sequences was pretty fast, taking around 3 minutes.

Comment: I will work on the script I promised and post it later (probably tomorrow).

Comment: I figured out a very fast way--using dictionaries, I can preallocate everything and go in the inverse direction--go through each substring in list1 and if they are present in the dictionary where list2 strings are the keys, then I can add one to that value. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this task can be solved in linear time with an [Aho Corasick string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) machine.
**See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288960/efficient-strings-containing-each-other/8289199#8289199) answer** for additional information (maybe you get ideas from the other answers to that question, too - it is almost the same task and I think Aho Corasick is the theoretically fastest way to solve this).

You will have to modify the string matching machine in such way, that instead of returning the match it increases the counter of every matched substring by one. (This should be only a minor modification).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you could avoid having some sort of O(n**2) algorithm. Here is a simple implementation.

```
>>> def some_sort_of_count(list1, list2):
>>>     return [sum(x in y for y in list1) for x in list2]
>>> 
>>> list1 = ['cat', 'caa', 'doa', 'oat']
>>> list2 = ['at', 'ca', 'do']
>>> some_sort_of_count(list1, list2)
[2, 2, 1]
```